# Google Calendar events to Google Sheers automatic refresh with onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, triggers

I am trying to grab time events from my Google Calendar into a Google Spreadsheet.

When a new time-event is created in my Google Calendar this event should be automatically synchronized into my Google Spreadsheet. This should be done automatically by an `onEdit` event trigger.

At the moment it is only running by refreshing the Google Spreadsheet.

Maybe someone has a better solution for my challenge. Here is my code:

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myCalendar')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function myCalendar(){

  var now=new Date();

 // Startzeit
  var startpoint=new Date(now.getTime()-60*60*24*365*1000);
  // Endzeit
  var endpoint=new Date(now.getTime()+60*60*24*1000*1000);

  var events=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("your-calendar-ID").getEvents(startpoint, endpoint);

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST"); 

  ss.clear(); 

  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

         ss.getRange(i+1,1 ).setValue(events[i].getTitle());
         ss.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(events[i].getDescription());
         ss.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(events[i].getStartTime());
         ss.getRange(i+1,4).setValue(events[i].getEndTime());
   }
 }
```

Comment: There is no trigger on calendar events. You are seeing this in the wrong direction. OnEdit is a trigger for spreadsheet events. The only way to go is a time driven trigger that checks the calendar regularly..

Comment: Thanks Serge insas ... You are right. This was one of my misunderstandings on triggers. They only run on spreadsheet events ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

Execute a function updating a spreadsheet when an event in Google Calendar is created.

**Solution**

Use the `EventUpdated` installable trigger that is fired each time an event is modified in Calendar (e.g. created, updated, or deleted - see reference). From there, you can go the easy way (update all data in the spreadsheet with a built-in `CalendarApp` class) or the hard way (update data that was changed with incremental sync - see official guide).

**Part 0 - install trigger**

```
/**
 * Installs Calendar trigger;
 */
function calendarTrigger() {
  var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('callback name here')
  .forUserCalendar('calendar owners email here')
  .onEventUpdated()
  .create();
}
```

**Part 1 - callback (Calendar -> Spreadsheet)**

```
/**
 * Updates spreadsheet;
 * @param {Object} e event object;
 */
function updateSpreadsheet(e) {  
  //access spreadsheet;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('target spreadsheet id');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('target sheet name');
  var datarng = sh.getDataRange(); //assumed that data is only calendar data;

  //access calendar;
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e.calendarId);

  //set timeframes;
  var start = new Date();
  var end =new Date();

  //get year before and three after;
  start.setFullYear(start.getFullYear()-1);
  end.setFullYear(end.getFullYear()+3);

  //get events;
  var events = calendar.getEvents(start, end);

  //map events Array to a two-dimensional array of values;
  events = events.map(function(event){
    return [event.getTitle(),event.getDescription(),event.getStartTime(),event.getEndTime()];
  });

  //clear values;
  datarng.clear();

  //setup range;
  var rng = sh.getRange(1,1, events.length, events[0].length);

  //apply changes;
  rng.setValues(events);
}
```

**Notes**

1. As per Tanaike's comment - it is important to account for triggers (both simple and installable) to **not firing** if event is triggered via script or request (see restrictions reference). To enable such feature you will have to introduce *polling* or bundle with a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that the script will call after creating an event (see below for a bundling sample).
2. Your solution is better suited for backwards flow: edit in spreadsheet -> edit in Calendar (if you modify it to perform ops on Calendar instead of updating the spreadsheet, ofc).
3. Make use of `Date` built-in object's methods like `getFullYear()` (see reference for other methods) to make your code more flexible and easier to understand. Btw, I would store "ms in a day" data as a constant (`86400000`).
4. Never use `getRange()`, `getValue()`, `setValue()` and similar methods in a loop (and in general call them as little as possible) - they are I/O methods and thus are slow (you can see for yourself by trying to write >200 rows in a loop). Get ranges/values needed at the start, perform modifications and write them in bulk (e.g. with `setValues()` method).

**Reference**

1. `EventUpdated` event [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events);
2. Calendar incremental synchronization [guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync);
3. `Date` built-in object [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date);
4. `setValues()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);
5. [Using batch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) operations in Google Apps Script;
6. [Installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) and [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) triggers restrictions;

---

### WebApp bundling

**Part 0 - prerequisites**

If you want to create / update / remove calendar events via script executions, you can bundle the target script with a simple WebApp. You'll need to make sure that:

1. The WebApp is deployed with access set as `anyone, even anonymous` (it is strongly recommended to introduce some form of request authentication);
2. WebApp code has **one** function named `doPost` accepting event object (conventionally named `e`, but it's up to you) as a single argument.

**Part 1 - build a WebApp**

This build assumes that all modifications are made in the WebApp, but you can, for example, return callback name to run on successfull request and handle updates in the calling script. As only the `calendarId` property of the event object is used in the callback above, we can pass to it a custom object with only this property set:

```
/**
 * Callback for POST requests (always called "doPost");
 * @param {Object} e event object;
 * @return {Object} TextOutput;
 */
function doPost(e) {
  //access request params;
  var body = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  //access calendar id;
  var calendarId = body.calendar;

  if(calendarId) {
    updateSpreadsheet({calendarId:calendarId}); //callback;
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success');
  }else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid request');
  }
}
```

**Part 2 - sample calling script**

This build assumes that calling script and the WebApp are the same script project (thus its Url can be accessed via `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`, otherwise paste the one provided to you during WebApp deployment). Being familiar with `UrlFetchApp` (see [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)) is required for the build.

```
/**
 * Creates event;
 */
function createEvent() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('your calendar id here');

  //modify whatever you need to (this build creates a simple event);
  calendar.createEvent('TEST AUTO', new Date(), new Date()); 

  //construct request parameters;
  var params = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      calendar: calendar.getId()
    })
  };

  //send request and handle result;
  var updated = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(),params);
  Logger.log(updated); //should log "Success";
}
```

Comment: I think that this is a good answer. As an additional information, how about adding the information that the event trigger is fired when the event is manually created , updated and deleted? I thought that such information might be useful for OP and other users.

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks! Agreed, will update accordingly, it is indeed important to know that triggers only fire manually (if I recall correctly, this is a general restriction on triggers, both simple and installable)

Answer (score 0):

```html
enter code here
// There are can be many calendar in one calendar of user like his main calendar, created calendar, holiday, etc.
// This function will clear all previous trigger from each calendar of user and create new trigger for remaining calendar of the user.
function createTriggers() {
  clearAllTriggers();
  let calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  calendars.forEach(cal => {
 
ScriptApp.newTrigger("calendarUpdate").forUserCalendar(cal.id).onEventUpdated().create();
  });
}

/* This trigger will provide us the calendar ID from which the event was fired, then you can perform your CalendarApp and sheet operation. If you want to synchronize new update more efficiently then use Calendar Advance Service, which will provide you with synchronization token that you can use to retrieve only updated and added events in calendar.
*/
function calendarUpdate(e) {
  logSyncedEvents(e.calendarId);
}

function clearAllTriggers() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  triggers.forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getEventType() == ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EVENT_UPDATED) ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
  });
}
```